# How can I find out if a hstore is a subset of another hstore?

Tags: postgresql, hstore

I have two `hstore` fields, that I want to compare, and I want to know if the one is a subset of the other?

So, let's say I have `"foo"=>"bar","fnuggle"=>"snuggle","dwurp"=>"qwork"` and `"dwurp"=>"qwork"`, the result would be `TRUE`.

When I have `"foo"=>"bar","fnuggle"=>"snuggle","dwurp"=>"qwork"` and `"dwurp"=>"dworp"`, the result should be `FALSE`.

Also, when I have `"foo"=>"bar","fnuggle"=>"snuggle","dwurp"=>"qwork"` and `"dwurp"=>"qwork","flippin"=>"floppin"`, the result should be `FALSE`.

I worked through the `hstore` operators and other possibilities, but didn't find a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turned out to be pretty simple. Consider `big` to be the superset and `small` the subset, this:

```
slice(big, akeys(small)) = small
```

returns `TRUE` when `small` is a subset.